# Symfony2 and Twig: how to prevent render of labels?

Tags: symfony, twig

As said in title. I have a form type and have to render some fields without labels (because I have to fit them into table's cells).
How can I do that?

Online documentation seems to be very low quality for that cases.

Comment: `Online documentation seems to be very low quality for that cases.` - please create an issue on the [symfony docs issue tracker](http://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues) and tell us what needs to become better or fix it yourself and create a Pull Request!

Comment: @WouterJ: I'll do... And next week I'll try your tip. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to change the default behavior.. you easly could render only inputs and labels in your template.

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ form_label(form.fieldName) }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ form_errors(form.fieldName) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.fieldName) }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

if you dont render the whole form, dont forget about the `{{ form_widget(form._token) }}` or more simple use `{{ form_rest(form) }}`

Comment: Please, underline the fact that form_widget will render only text-field value of the field but applied to the entire form, will act in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own 'form theme' as described in [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#form-theming). You can use the methods `form_label`, `form_errors` and `form_widget` to style where you want it. If you don't want the label you don't use the `form_label` function and just only the `form_errors` and `form_widget` functions:

```html
{# src/Acme/TaskBundle/Resources/views/Form/fields.html.twig #}
{% block form_row %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="form_row">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```